# CAEmitterCell particle position

Tags: objective-c, xcode, caemittercell

I have a snow falling animation using the uiview particle emitter. I am able to animate the snow in various ways thanks to much research, including changing the image content of the particles. There is a circular region where I would like to change the snow image of the particles, and then change the image back when the particle leaves the region. (snow falling through lamp light)

I was thinking of cooking up a formula to switch content images based on the position of the particle in a animation loop, but I am unable to get the x, y of the particle. Is it possible to get the position of individual particles?

Or perhaps particle collision detection?

Comment: Hi Nick, any lucky with that? I'm kind of looking for something like that, and so far no solution was found.

Comment: Methinks you could use the layer's bitmap to find the pixels that make up the particles.